# Getting Duplicate results when using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have 3 tables. One with user names, one with a bunch of data, and then one that links the 2 tables together via their ID's. When I try and join the 3 with an INNER JOIN, I get a bunch of duplicate rows. For example, if the data table only has 2000 rows, once I try and use the inner join to connect the 3 tables, I get an output that shows 100,000 rows. Does this have something to do with the fact that my Data table has more rows than my User name table and the inner join doesn't play nicely? Is it possible to inner join one table that has more rows than the other?

***EDIT FOR CLEARITY***

For this database I import data that looks something like this:

```
-Names-----------Numbers-----------Item---------------Cost---
John Smith       111-1111          Pencils           100.75  
Joe Stevens      222-2222          Paper             35.34  
Mike Jones       333-3333          Staples           23.86
John Smith       111-1111          Boxes             11.76
```

As you can see John Smith is listed twice, for two separate items. I would like to optimize this, but separating the original data and putting things in their own table with only one iteration.

```
  ID---Name---           ID----Numbers            ID---Items------Cost
  1    John Smith        1    111-1111            1    Pencil     100.75
  2    Joe Stevens       2    222-2222            2    Paper      35.34
  3    Mike Jones        3    333-3333            3    Staples    23.86
                                                  4    Boxes      11.76
```

Now that things are optimized, I need to be able to still run a query that could match John Smith with both the pencils and the boxes. This is why I created the link table that holds the IDs in the correct sequence they need to be in.

```
          Name.ID           Number.ID        Item.ID
            1                  1                1
            2                  2                2 
            3                  3                3
            1                  1                4
```

Now if I wanted to run a report that recreates the original data dump, I would run a query that just joins the 3 tables with an inner join. The issue though, is that I'm getting results with tons of duplicates, rather than just simply outputting that data as it should be. I get something like this:

```
-Names-----------Numbers-----------Item---------------Cost---
John Smith       111-1111          Pencils           100.75 
John Smith       111-1111          Pencils           100.75 
John Smith       111-1111          Pencils           100.75  
John Smith       111-1111          Pencils           100.75 
John Smith       111-1111          Pencils           100.75  
Joe Stevens      222-2222          Paper             35.34 
Joe Stevens      222-2222          Paper             35.34
Joe Stevens      222-2222          Paper             35.34
Joe Stevens      222-2222          Paper             35.34 
Mike Jones       333-3333          Staples           23.86
Mike Jones       333-3333          Staples           23.86
Mike Jones       333-3333          Staples           23.86
Mike Jones       333-3333          Staples           23.86
John Smith       111-1111          Boxes             11.76
John Smith       111-1111          Boxes             11.76
John Smith       111-1111          Boxes             11.76
John Smith       111-1111          Boxes             11.76
```

The desired output would simply be:

```
-Names-----------Numbers-----------Item---------------Cost---
John Smith       111-1111          Pencils           100.75  
Joe Stevens      222-2222          Paper             35.34  
Mike Jones       333-3333          Staples           23.86
John Smith       111-1111          Boxes             11.76
```

Comment: It seems you have a junction table. A junction table is designed to allow a number or records to be associated with another number of records, so two names may have ten data each equaling 2 x 10 records.

Comment: Hmmm, so you are saying instead of linking things together, they are being multiplied?

Comment: No, I am saying that each name validly has more than one data.

Comment: Consider, "please select all colours that you like."

Comment: Well yes. I've got a chunk of data that im importing in, and it includes many duplicate entries in each column. As a result I separate things out into different tables and create just one version of each record. Username table only has one version of each name, and so on. When I run a query I need to be able to "recreate" the original data dump if necessary, linking the duplicate usernames with their corresponding data. Thats why I used the junction table. Not sure if that makes things clearer lol? Sorry

Comment: No, it does not make things clearer. You need to state in detail what you have and what you want. Sample data is a good idea.

Comment: alright give me a second and I will update the original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65490/discussion-between-fionnuala-and-user1781966).

Comment: I am here but not much longer

Comment: You should show the SELECT command that you use to get theese duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Select Distinct t1.Names,t2.Number,t3.Item,t3.Cost
From  
tableName t1  
inner join tableNum t2  
on t1.ID = t2.ID  
inner join tableItem t3  
on t1.ID = t3.ID
```

Comment: Not a good idea to mask problems in database design by using DISTINCT.

Comment: This will not run in MS Access.

Comment: @python_newbie when getting duplicates it has some reason, if you do not investigate the reason and just use DISTINCT, you get slow queries and perhaps some other problems with primary data in the future. https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2008/11/11/60752.aspx